When my modem places a signal on coax, is that signal still considered Ethernet?
If I'm using 10BASE-T, 100BASE-TX, or 1000BASE-T Ethernet on my home LAN and need to reach out to the internet, my modem will need to translate the routers LAN signals such that they can operate on coax over longer distances.
This new signal that is placed on coax - is it still considered Ethernet?


This new signal that is placed on coax - is it still considered
Ethernet?

No.
Ethernet is a series of physical (various media) and data-link protocols (very few variants). The (obsolete) 10Base-5, 10Base-2, and 10Broad-36 versions of ethernet ran on coax. There are some special variants of ethernet that run on coax or other media for short distances, but the most common variants run on different standards of UTP and fiber.*
Cable modems use the DOCSIS (Data Over Cable Service Interface Specification) standard to run on a hybrid coax/fiber infrastructure.

*This answer, while not completely inclusive of all, lists many different ethernet variants, some of which are obsolete or only used in special cases, e.g. inside a device
.

There's actually 10GPASS-XR EPoC (IEEE 802.3bn-2016) - hybrid over coax and fiber - but I'm not sure whether that's in use at all.

I have only seen DOCSIS used for cable modems. I would assume the IEEE standard would be only for ethernet, not on a commercial cable infrastructure that also carries video and audio as a service.

@Ron-Maupin  Our commercial cable is DOCSIS 3.1, but it no longer carries video and audio channels.  And the last round of network hardware upgrade completely removed that capability from our cable head ends.

Also worth mentioning MoCA. While DOCSIS is usually used for ISP to customer last-mile connections, MoCA is usually used for networking over coax inside a home.

Depends on which family of terminology you're considering.
At the physical layer: it's no longer Ethernet despite coax having superficial similarity with the media used by a 10BASE2 network.
At the data link layer: it might still use frames which are fundamentally Ethernet, i.e. have the same size limitations, checksums, and same way of indicating what the next-higher layer is. The details depend on whose cables and endpoint equipment are being used.

If it's a modem, then the coax side is not Ethernet, as no modulation would be needed.

@OrangeDog Hasn't the term "modem" become abused to the point where we can't expect everything called a "modem" to actually modulate and demodulate analog signals? Obviously the physical layer has to use analog signaling, but if we consider that to make something a modem, then all physical network interfaces would be modems.

@ToddWilcox no? It's pretty clear which devices are modems, and which are switches, routers, or other such things. The typical home network hub is all three, with the modem part handling the DOCSIS interface.

@OrangeDog The typical home device called a "modem" isn't a true modem since it does not modulate and demodulate analog signals in the classic sense. DOCSIS is digital, so we normally wouldn't say that converting to and from Ethernet to DOCSIS is "modulating" or "demodulating"

@ToddWilcox In fairness, OP didn't specify DOCSIS or any other specific encoding. "MODEM"- in its original sense- could potentially include modulation (or selection) of any carrier including DC, so basically you're throwing CODEC into the mix: the endpoint is a MODEM/CODEC/router/switch.

@ToddWilcox Are you sure DOCSIS is digital? The references to QAM and OFDM look like analog sine waves to me. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOCSIS#Physical_layer

@ToddWilcox If that's the case, then 2.5, 5, and 10GBase-T NICs are "modems," as the transmitted signal is continuous amplitude, thanks to Tomlinson-Harashima precoding.

@user71659 I’m not sure if you meant to agree with me but you are. Neither cable “modems” nor NICs are actually modems. The former are called “modems” for reasons I do not know, but they are not modems in the strictest sense. The old school dial-up modems are modems, since they convert digital signals to analog signals and back.

@ToddWilcox As I said, 2.5GBase-T and above uses a continuous-amplitude "analog" signal, so they're "modems" by your definition.

@user71659 If PAM constellations used in NBASE-T signaling are analog, then almost everything is analog so everything is a modem. This would defeat the whole point of having distinct concepts of analog vs digital signaling. Just because analog PAM exists doesn't mean all PAM is analog.

@ToddWilcox No, it's not PAM. As I said, it's Tomlinson-Harashima precoding.

@user71659 Regardless of what aspect of NBase-T or cable modem technology you want to talk about, I’m never going to agree that either of those are best described as “analog” in the same way I expect we would agree that AM radio, NTSC, and 1950s telephony are analog.

@ToddWilcox You're running in circles. A Bell 202 modem converts discrete-time discrete-valued data for transmission over twisted pair copper with some DC bias. A 10GBase-T NIC converts discrete-time discrete-valued data for transmission over twisted pair copper without DC bias. So modem channels require DC bias?

@ToddWilcox Leaving aside that some cable systems modulate carriers in various ways, consider this. FM/FSK both select from available carrier frequencies to convey data. AM has one of these be 0Hz, baseband signalling has both 0Hz with a level difference. QAM etc. have multiple frequencies but again it is selection. All of those have been used for equipment which is undeniably termed a modem. I really don't see why xBASE-Y should be any different, so while it is unarguably wrong to call a modern switch/router/etc. "a modem", it's entirely acceptable to say that it /contains/ a modem subsystem.
